# Core data id auto increment

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, auto-increment

I found a subject where they're something named objectID to get the auto increment id of every lines of a table, I want to get it and display it, but I don't understand how to do, my code:

```
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let newDemande = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Demandes", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    newDemande.setValue(soapRequest.xmlString, forKey: "xml")
    newDemande.setValue(1, forKey: "statutenvoie")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("erreur data")
    }

    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Demandes")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                let xml = item.valueForKey("xml")
                let statutenvoie = item.valueForKey("statutenvoie")

                print(xml!, statutenvoie!)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("erreur data")
    }
```

Error :

```
print(item.objectID)
```

> 2016-01-07 10:53:22.679 ...[956:28002] CoreData: error:
>   -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/informatiqueresponis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FF92B583-0288-41FE-AD09-718E7E66D457/data/Containers/Data/Application/B851E6CE-C0C9-4FEE-9400-587995198D50/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite
>   options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Demandes = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "2654FBD8-4C1B-4001-827A-5C9D471B19C4";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with
>   userInfo dictionary {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Demandes = ;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "2654FBD8-4C1B-4001-827A-5C9D471B19C4";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"; } 2016-01-07 10:53:22.683
>   ...[956:28002] Unresolved error Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN
>   Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the
>   application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a632aa0 {Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Demandes = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "2654FBD8-4C1B-4001-827A-5C9D471B19C4";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the
>   application's saved data.}, [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to
>   initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 640;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Demandes = ;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "2654FBD8-4C1B-4001-827A-5C9D471B19C4";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the
>   application's saved data.] (lldb)

Comment: That error is not caused by that line of code. It tells you which method caused the error-- `addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:URL:options:error:`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to [objectID in the NSManagedObject class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObject/objectID):

```
var objectID: NSManagedObjectID { get }
```

In your case try:

```
if results.count > 0 {
        for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
            let xml = item.valueForKey("xml")
            let statutenvoie = item.valueForKey("statutenvoie")

            print(item.objectID)
            print(xml!, statutenvoie!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ben That looks like an error when tinkering with the model. Stop the app, delete it from the simulator, clean project, build it and run again.